Javascript not working on Safari console, but works in Chrome
I'm trying to simulate a click from console on the 3rd upload box.
This code works in Chrome. I can browse my folder, but it's not working in Safari.
setTimeout(function() {
  // Sélectionner tous les éléments avec la classe 'uP74h0hWZUzbcqM1doHG IazVbeuKn6e3j5HwOjS7 newImgCreate'
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.uP74h0hWZUzbcqM1doHG.IazVbeuKn6e3j5HwOjS7.newImgCreate');
  
  if (elements.length >= 3) {
    // Sélectionner le 3ème élément dans la liste (index 2)
    let thirdElement = elements[2];
    
    // Chercher un enfant cliquable à l'intérieur (comme un bouton ou icône)
    let clickableChild = thirdElement.querySelector('kat-icon[name="add_a_photo"]') || thirdElement.querySelector('button, input, [role="button"]');
    
    if (clickableChild) {
      clickableChild.click();  // Simuler un clic sur l'élément enfant cliquable
      console.log('Clic simulé sur un élément enfant cliquable du 3ème élément');
    } else {
      console.log('Aucun enfant cliquable trouvé dans le 3ème élément');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Moins de 3 éléments trouvés');
  }
}, 1000);

Snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/m0y2o95s/

hard to tell as it depends on extremal Html, as a general idea try simplifying it until it starts working in both browsers.

i simplifyed it but still : document.querySelector('#ProductImage_MAIN-display kat-icon[name="add_a_photo"]')?.click();

what are you trying to achieve? click has some browser specifics please see impl. notes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click, chrome/safary are close relatives in terms of behavior but anything is possible.

i just want trough console of safari simulate a click on input field. normaly when you click on it it open file browser so you can select what you want to uplaod. Work easily with chrome but not in safari.

Maybe worth checking that it finds the element by selector as you use a forgiving ?. when calling click()

like this ? : document.querySelector('#ProductImage_MAIN-input_input').click();

take any webpage that propose upload something. let s say file io, in console with chrome paste :document.querySelector('label[for="upload-button"]')?.click();
then browser will open up, now do same with safari and nothing happening. atleast only for me ?
